# Syntax error in Access SQL query inner join

Tags: sql, syntax-error, inner-join, ms-access-2010

I have written the following query in MS Access SQL:

```
UPDATE [B-K Data]
SET [Supplier 1] = [PNTestImport].[MFR], [Supplier 1 order no] = [PNTestImport].[MFR_PN]
FROM [PNTestImport]
INNER JOIN [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import] on [B-K Data].[B-K no] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[BK PN]
INNER JOIN  [PNTestImport] on  [PNTestImport].[ITEM_NUMBER] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[Analogic PN];
```

I get a syntax error when I try to run the query, but no identification of where the problem lies.

When Googling the error, I found other with similar problem but no answer that works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Quote the error in full then.

Comment: using space in database object name is NOT recommend, although there is no actual harm if you remember always include `[ brackets ]` ( this is already a point not to do this), but imagine you accidentally type double space and spend hours just to find out where the typo is.

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings. For compiler errors chop code until OK & add back. Runtime find & show input & output up to the 1st point that doesn't have the program in the state you expect. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. (Debugging fundamentals.) For code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [help]  Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `FROM` in an Access `UPDATE` clause. Tables are specified directly after `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE [B-K Data]
INNER JOIN [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import] on [B-K Data].[B-K no] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[BK PN]
INNER JOIN  [PNTestImport] on  [PNTestImport].[ITEM_NUMBER] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[Analogic PN]
SET [Supplier 1] = [PNTestImport].[MFR], [Supplier 1 order no] = [PNTestImport].[MFR_PN]
```

Note that this also means all tables are editable in a single `UPDATE` clause, and all tables must be writable. There also cannot be ambiguity through joins, which can lead to problems with many-many matches.

Answer (score 0):

In ms access you need  () parentheses  ro the form clause with join around the

```
UPDATE [B-K Data]
SET [Supplier 1] = [PNTestImport].[MFR], [Supplier 1 order no] = [PNTestImport].[MFR_PN]
FROM (( [PNTestImport]
INNER JOIN [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import] on 
       [B-K Data].[B-K no] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[BK PN])
INNER JOIN  [PNTestImport] on 
       [PNTestImport].[ITEM_NUMBER] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[Analogic PN]);
```